# SwitchCompat text not showing up on action bar

Tags: android-layout, android-menu, android-actionbar-compat, android-switch, switchcompat

I have an action bar on my app and inside the action bar there is a SwitchCompat widget. I've gotten the widget to show up on the action bar but there is no text beside the switch when I test the app.

Here's my menu.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_switch"
        android:title="Switch"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_item"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat" />
</menu>
```

Here's my actionview xml file that contains the SwitchCompat widget

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
        android:text="Night Mode"
        android:showText="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see, I've already added `android:text="Night Mode"` and `android:showText="true"` in my action view file. However, the text still doesn't show up. How do I go about this?

[image: Picture of current action bar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why I could not set the text statically before runtime in the xml file but I solved it dynamically by setting the text of the SwitchCompat in my code.

Here's the Kotlin code:

```
 override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.app_menu, menu);
        val nightMode= menu?.findItem(R.id.app_bar_switch)
        val actionView:SwitchCompat= nightMode?.actionView as SwitchCompat
        actionView.text = "Night Mode"
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```